# What experiment could I run in order to test the 'Independence of Irrelevant Alternatives' axiom?

Tags: mathematical-economics, behavioral-economics, experimental-economics

I need some help in designing an economics experiment to test the IIA axiom. My understanding of it is if you rank A above B then if you introduce C or D, you must still always rank A above B in any order.

The experiment should be cheap to run and it needs treatment and control variables.

Comment: It's been pretty amply studied. Almost any paper on the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoy_effect is a good example. The most reproducible violations are actually in a lab (rather than real world) setting, so just gather some undergraduates and make them make some fictitious purchases.